# Mouse Cursor is not changing to Pointer on <a> href in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a question it could look silly but its driving me crazy for hours. in asp.net core MVC.
the Mouse Cursor when hovering over a href is not chaning to hand pointer, even though I set it to in the href itself e.g.

```
<a href="#" style="cursor:pointer!important;">Goto Link</a>
```

when I run my project the cursor is still an arrow and not changing to hand pointer on hover,
I installed the latest version of boostrap and tried also no luck.
any help?
thanks.

Comment: `cursor:pointer !important` Does it make a difference putting a space between pointer and !important?

Comment: Its Perfectly working for me.
Can you please elaborate in details?
In which Browser u getting trouble ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its all about the Browser, I Figured it out,
for some reason edge is not doing it on a specific machine, I accessed the site from another machine and it worked, fine.